# Customize list label via optional argument

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'm writing a syllabus for a class for which I created a custom `enumerate` environment, `class`, that formats it the way I want. The key is that it automatically adds the word "Class X", where X is the counter. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{classes}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[classes]{
        label=\textbf{Class \arabic*: },
        labelindent=0pt,
        itemindent=0pt,
        leftmargin=!
        style = multiline,
        labelwidth = 50pt,
        before=\setlength{\listparindent}{-\leftmargin},    
    }
\begin{document}
\section*{Syllabus}
Syllabus description.
\begin{classes}
\subsection*{I. Introduction and framework}
\item foo.
\end{classes}
\end{document}
```

What I haven't been able to achieve is to add an optional argument to `\item` to identify is the class will be, say, Theoretical or Practical. Something like

```
\item[t] theoretical class
\item[p] practical class
```

The idea is that if the option is specified, then the word "Theoretical" or "Practical" is printed below the label. So the output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is the item text supposed to wrap or is it just a one liner?

Comment: Ideally it would wrap right after "Class X:"

Comment: I meant the text in place of “this is a theoretical class”

Comment: Yes, it's suppose to wrap (it will be a paragraph-length description of the class with a nested itemize for readings).

Answer (score 2):

A version with `[t]` or `[p]` support (wrapped label lines)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newtoggle{classtoggle}%
\newif\iftheoreticalclass


\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\classcellwidth}
\setlength{\classcellwidth}{60pt}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\theoclass}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\classcellwidth}}%
    \textbf{Class \number\value{#1}:}  \tabularnewline
    \bfseries Theoretical
  \end{tabular}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\practicalclass}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\classcellwidth}}%
    \textbf{Class \number\value{#1}:}  \tabularnewline
    \bfseries Practical
  \end{tabular}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\defaultclass}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\classcellwidth}}%
    \textbf{Class \number\value{#1}:}  \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\classctr}[1]{\classctrint{#1}}
\newcommand{\classctrint}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{classtoggle}{%
    \iftheoreticalclass%
    \theoclass{#1}%
    \else
    \practicalclass{#1}%
    \fi%
  }{%
    \defaultclass{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\AddEnumerateCounter*{\classctr}{\classctrint}{40}

    \newlist{classes}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[classes]{%
      label=\classctr*,
      labelindent=0pt,
      itemindent=0pt,
      leftmargin=!
      style = multiline,
      labelwidth = 50pt,
      before=\setlength{\listparindent}{-\leftmargin},    
    }

\LetLtxMacro\origitem\item

\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}{%
  \toggletrue{classtoggle}% Switch to use t or p mode temporarily
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \theoreticalclassfalse%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{t}{%
      \theoreticalclasstrue%
      \origitem%
    }{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{p}{%
        \theoreticalclassfalse%
        \origitem%
      }{% 
        \togglefalse{classtoggle}% No, it's neither p nor t
        \origitem[#1]%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \togglefalse{classtoggle}%
    \origitem
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Syllabus}
Syllabus description.
\begin{classes}
\subsection*{I. Introduction and framework}
\item[p] foo.
\item[t] bar
\item    None
\item[p]    Again
\end{classes}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[t] Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A preliminary version...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by creating a custom `\item` command, but I think there are probably better solutions. Anyway, this is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{classes}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[classes]{
  label=Class \arabic*:\protect\thiscitem,
  style = multiline,
  leftmargin=!,
  labelwidth = 60pt,
}
\newcommand{\citem}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\thiscitem{}%
  \else
    \def\thiscitem{\\(#1)}%
  \fi
  \item}
\begin{document}
\section*{Syllabus}
Syllabus description.
\begin{classes}
\subsection*{I. Introduction and framework}
\citem[Theoretical] foo.
\end{classes}
\end{document}
```

[image]